# Force gcc to pass the parameters on the stack

Tags: c, gcc, stack, parameter-passing, calling-convention

Is there a way to force gcc to pass the parameters of a function on the stack?

I don't want to use the registers for parameter passing.

**Update**: I'am using arm-gcc from [CodeSourcery](http://codesourcery.com)

Comment: Why is passing parameters in registers a bad thing?

Comment: It is not a bad thing. I just want the parameters to be passed in this way because I'am //emulating// a thread creation (and stack allocation) routine.

Comment: @RichardPennington what about reentrancy? If you have the input parameters on registers, what happens if the function is interrupted right after entering it but before you can make copies in local variables? Wouldn't that corrupt the input parameters of the first call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042d/IHI0042D_aapcs.pdf

> The first four registers r0-r3 (a1-a4)
>   are used to pass argument values into
>   a subroutine and to return a result
>   value from a function. They may also
>   be used to hold intermediate values
>   within a routine (but, in general,
>   only between subroutine calls).

There are, on ARM, no other calling conventions but the default, that I know of. And here is why:

1. Why would you want to? Your function would not be callable in compiled form by other functions, creating a compatibility mess.
2. Your calls to system functions which comply with the ABI wouldn't work, unless the compiler was able to differentiate between calling conventions. Now, I know in the past there are different calling conventions for [x86-32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), but notice how x64 is simpler (AMD64 vs whatever Microsoft did). Why, when designing the [ARM calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#ARM), would you allow so many different calling conventions? It creates a compatibility mess.

Comment: Yes you are right. It's an *odd* thing to this, especially because of the reasons you've mentioned. The idea is that the defined function was the main body of a thread -- in a custom environment (OS). The custom OS would push the argument of the thread on the stack. In order to respect the ABI, there are two workarounds: put the argument in the r0 or declare *thread_func(uint32_t r0, uint32_t r1, uint32_t r2, uint32_t r3, void *param)*. Thanks!

Comment: Why not put them into the registers anyway? You'd need to preserve registers across threads, but you have to anyway - imagine if you switched threads during execution and the old function's register values were left in place... if OSes did this, it would be very messy.

Comment: The thread is created from the userspace and there is no API (syscall) for setting a register value for the newly created thread.

Answer (score 2):

You can try wrapping the parameters in a structure; for example, if your function is `int calc_my_sum(int x, int y) {return x+y;}` you can change it as follows (ugly):

```
struct my_x_y {
    int x, y;
    my_x_y(): x(0), y(0) {} // a non-trivial constructor to make the type non-POD
};

int calc_my_sum(my_x_y x_and_y) {
    // passing non-POD object by value forces to use the stack
    return x_and_y.x + x_and_y.y;
}
```

Alternatively, you can just add 4 dummy parameters to use up the registers, so other parameters will use stack:

```
struct force_stack_usage {
    int dummy0, dummy1, dummy2, dummy3;
}

int calc_my_sum(force_stack_usage, int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

Comment: Nice hack! The first solution is C++ only, I forgot to mention that I needed a C solution. Thanks.

Comment: There is no need for a bizarre C++ constructor to achieve what you want. In C structs are simply copied on the stack. In C99 you could even call the function with `calc_my_sum((my_x_y){ .x = 5, .y = 7 })` or wrap such a thing in a macro without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Where to store a local variable is depend on how you will use it. If you need to get a local variable's address, the local variable can only be stored on the stack. So when you pass your subroutine a pointer, this parameter will be passed through the stack.